# How to programmatically import csv into excel and use excel formatting?

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsxwriter

I have a very large (> 2 million rows) csv file that is being generated and viewed in an internal web service. The problem is that when users of this system want to export this csv to run custom queries, they open these files in excel. Excel is formatting the numbers the best it can, but there are some requests to have the data in xlsx format with filters and whatnot.

The question boils down to: Using python2.7, how can I read a large csv file (>2 million rows) into excel (or multiple excel files) and control the formatting? (dates, numbers, autofilters, etc)

I am open to python and internal excel solutions.

Comment: You could use [tag:openpyxl], but its formatting capabilities are limited.  Another option is to use [tag:powershell], which I think has more formatting capability than `openpyxl`

Comment: another option is to use the python win32 extensions and use excel's COM interface. The trick is to crib existing VB scripts. But really, this is likely easier done in VB or C#.

Comment: I've never worked with powershell, VB, or C#. Right now xlsxWriter is performing really poorly and can't really handle the workload I am giving it (even in a copy this row from the csv to the xlsx).

Comment: XlsxWriter can handle all those features, formatting and autofilters, but 2 million rows is a lot of data and Excel has a limit of about 1 million rows per worksheet. Make sure to turn use the `constant_memory` mode in XlsxWriter but even so it will probably require about 15s per million cells (ballpark figure).

Comment: I ended up getting the performance I needed by using the multiprocessing library to normalize the data from the csv in one process and then pass it to other process to format into excel. When I have more time I'll post a minimum example of the solution with some performance stats.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about the data types in the csv, or your exact issue with EXCEL properly handling those data types, it's hard to give you an exact answer.

However, recommending looking at this module (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) which can be used in Python to create xlsx files.  I haven't used it, but it seems to have more features than you need.

Especially if you need to split between multiple files, or workbooks.  And it looks like you can pre-create the filters and have total control over the formating